# Nested sampling: estimate of bulk posterior support over prior

Tags: bayesian, sampling, posterior

Going through the details of the Nested sampling Skilling [paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1835238), and I've encountered an estimate in Section 5 which I cannot reproduce. Rephrasing what's mentioned in the paper:

we assume to have a likelihood in $C$ dimensions, and we approximate it with a rank $C$ multivariate normal. Likelihood values $$L\propto\exp(-\frac{r^2}{2})$$ enclose a prior mass $X\propto r^C$, where $r$ is a radius in C dimension.
Therefore the posterior $$\text{d}P\propto L \text{d}X=L X\text{d}\log X$$ induce a variance on $\log X$:

\begin{equation}
\langle \delta (\log X)^2\rangle\propto C/2
\end{equation}

So the posterior is broadly distributed over a range $-H \pm \sqrt{C}$ in $\log X$, where $H$ is the information 
$$H=\int\log(\frac{dP}{dX})dP$$

I cannot wrap my head around the estimate for the variance of $\log X$, and  the subsequent posterior bulk range. Have someone else gone through this derivation?

**EDIT: Proof attempt**

The quantity I need to compute is the variance of $\log X$ under the posterior distribution $dP$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int (\log X - \langle\log X\rangle )^2 dP & = & \int_0^1 (\log X - \langle\log X\rangle )^2 L dX\\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^{0} (Y - \langle Y\rangle )^2 \exp({-(\exp{Y})^{\frac{2}{C}})}\exp{Y}dY
\end{eqnarray}
however I cannot find the path down to the estimate $C/2$